# Getting Coda to connect FTP via Applescript?

Tags: ftp, applescript, coda

I have scoured Google and can't even come close to an answer but, Panic Coda support staffs says this can be done.

We use WHMCS as our billing system for all of our hosting clients. With 100's of clients, it's not practical to create Coda sites to connect via FTP, with passwords changing all the time.

What we've done so far....
So, we created a WHMCS hook to create a FTP link within that system so that when we can click that FTP link, it launches Yummy FTP and connects to the site. Easy.. Then we can double click any file and have it open in Coda.

What we want to do...
Is have an Applescript to catch that same click, get the FTP url (which is formatted like ftp://user:pass@site.com), then start coda and use that FTP url to open the remote FTP site.

This way we have FTP and editing all within Coda instead of having to cmd-tab all day to edit files.

Coda support says this can be done but, we have NO clue as to where to start on creating an applescript that does this.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!